# Find the starting point to do a rebase -i

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-squash

I am working in a branch (fork of master of course) and I have a series of commits.
I am interested in finding out exactly which commit is the one that is is where the branch started and is part of the master.

Why do I need this?
I want to squash all the commits with interactive rebase and I was wondering if there is an easy way to figure out what to pass to rebase command instead of manually counting commits to pass `HEAD~52`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) accepts two commits (which, as usual can be commit-hashes, branches, tags, etc) and returns the common ancestor they both diverged from.

E.g.:

```
mureinik@comupter ~/src/git/myproject [master] $ git merge-base master feature-1
7c2232a4dd6c54ee8cc3f693ab8a0020ad82410b
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the whole command would be: `git rebase -i $(git merge-base master HEAD)`.